# Is there any way to detect e-core and p-core?

Tags: c#, .net

My project is made in C# WPF .Net Framework 4.8

It's been 3-rd day of trying to detect hybrid processor in Windows and get all threads and cores data (List of cores with int core, isPCore, isHyperthreaded).

Only thing that I found is [this guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/12th-gen-intel-core-processor-gamedev-guide.html) from intel, but it is on C++.

I've tried to make a dll out of it. It works tho, **but** Windows defender and other AVs detects viruses. And it's happening even my app is signed, and false alarm reports not helping at all. Using c++ dll in c# also makes it hard to embbed dll into portable exe.

Comment: What do you intend to use the information for? The main use case I can think of would be applications that are both highly latency sensitive, and has a high load.  C# is probably not ideal for that scenario due to the Garbage collection.

Comment: @JonasH I need this information to make tests of p-cores and e-cores. Especially for games. Most of the gamedevs not optimizing games for those type of processors. Literally every FPS test shows that, disabling e-cores does not affect games performance. So, I thought, what if, I can integrate to my app service or additional background process that will reorganize affinity of every process in windows to give more CPU room on p-cores to run games or other apps that need like more single core performace.

Comment: Allocating CPU resources on a hybrid CPU for best performance is *really difficult*. Trying to do so without access to either the application code or the OS scheduler even more so. I do not think you would do a better job than intel & microsoft engineers. You might be able to do something like a lookup table, if CPU=i7_1370 && application=gamename.exe, then set affinity to x. Making statements like "disabling e cores does not affect games performance" is can be dangerous since it could very well change with newer CPUs, schedulers, and games.